# Resize image faster in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a lot of image files in a folder (5M+). These images are of different sizes. I want to resize these images to `128x128`.

I used the following function in a loop to resize in Python using OpenCV

```
def read_image(img_path):
    # print(img_path)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
    return img

for file in tqdm(glob.glob('train-images//*.jpg')):
    img = read_image(file)
    img = cv2.imwrite(file, img)
```

But it will take more than 7 hours to complete. I was wondering whether there are any method to speed up this process.

Can I implement parallel processing to do this efficiently with `dask` or something.? If so how is it possible.?

Comment: just to make sure, you're intending to overwrite the originals?

Comment: @Aaron, Yes I am trying to over-write the files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are absolutely intent on doing this in Python, then please just disregard my answer. If you are interested in getting the job done simply and fast, read on...

I would suggest **GNU Parallel** if you have lots of things to be done in parallel and even more so as CPUs become *"fatter"* with more cores rather than *"taller"* with higher clock rates (GHz).

At its simplest, you can use **ImageMagick** just from the command line in Linux, macOS and Windows like this to resize a bunch of images:

```
magick mogrify -resize 128x128\! *.jpg
```

If you have hundreds of images, you would be better running that in parallel which would be:

```
parallel magick mogrify -resize 128x128\! ::: *.jpg
```

If you have millions of images, the expansion of `*.jpg` will overflow your shell's command buffer, so you can use the following to feed the image names in on `stdin` instead of passing them as parameters:

```
find -iname \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 -X --eta magick mogrify -resize 128x128\!
```

There are two *"tricks"* here:

- I use `find ... -print0` along with `parallel -0` to null-terminate filenames so there are no problems with spaces in them,
- I use `parallel -X` which means, rather than start a whole new `mogrify` process for each image, **GNU Parallel** works out how many filenames `mogrify` can accept, and gives it that many in batches.

I commend both tools to you.

---

Whilst the **ImageMagick** aspects of the above answer work on Windows, I don't use Windows and I am unsure about using **GNU Parallel** there. I *think* it maybe runs under `git-bash` and/or maybe under `Cygwin` - you could try asking a separate question - they are free!

As regards the ImageMagick part, I think you can get a listing of all the JPEG filenames in a file using this command:

```
DIR /S /B *.JPG > filenames.txt
```

You can then *probably* process them (not in parallel) like this:

```
magick mogrify -resize 128x128\! @filenames.txt
```

And if you find out how to run **GNU Parallel** on Windows, you can *probably* process them in parallel using something like this:

```
parallel --eta -a filenames.txt magick mogrify -resize 128x128\!
```

Comment: I have added what little I know about Windows.

Comment: GNU Parallel is tested on both git-bash and CygWin at least once per year. Basic functionality works. File a bug report if advanced functionality does not.

Answer (score 4):

If these images are stored on a magnetic hard drive, you may very well find you are limited by read/write speed (lots of small reads and writes are very slow on spinning magnetic disks).

Otherwise you can always throw the problem at a processing pool to utilize multiple cores:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
from ctypes import c_int
import time, cv2, os

wdir = r'C:\folder full of large images'
os.chdir(wdir)

def read_imagecv2(img_path, counter):
    # print(img_path)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
    cv2.imwrite('resized_'+img_path, img) #write the image in the child process (I didn't want to overwrite my images)
    with counter.get_lock(): #processing pools give no way to check up on progress, so we make our own
        counter.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start 4 worker processes
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool: #this should be the same as your processor cores (or less)
        counter = Value(c_int, 0) #using sharedctypes with mp.dummy isn't needed anymore, but we already wrote the code once...
        chunksize = 4 #making this larger might improve speed (less important the longer a single function call takes)
        result = pool.starmap_async(read_imagecv2, #function to send to the worker pool
                                    ((file, counter) for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if file.endswith('.jpg')),  #generator to fill in function args
                                    chunksize) #how many jobs to submit to each worker at once
        while not result.ready(): #print out progress to indicate program is still working.
            #with counter.get_lock(): #you could lock here but you're not modifying the value, so nothing bad will happen if a write occurs simultaneously
            #just don't `time.sleep()` while you're holding the lock
            print("\rcompleted {} images   ".format(counter.value), end='')
            time.sleep(.5)
        print('\nCompleted all images')
```

Due to a [somewhat known](https://forums.fast.ai/t/why-doesnt-opencv-seem-to-work-with-multiprocessing/14743) problem with `cv2` not playing nice with multiprocessing, we can use threads instead of processes by replacing `multiprocessing.Pool` with `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`. Many openCV functions release the GIL anyway, so we still should see the computational benefit of using multiple cores at once. Additionally this reduces some amount of overhead, as threads aren't as heavy as processes. After some investigating I have not found an image library that does play nice with processes. They all seem to fail when trying to pickle a function to send to the child processes (how items of work are sent to child processes for computation).

Comment: I will try and let you know the results

Comment: Code ran without any error, it showed the tqdm progress bar but it was at 100% by a 1 second and as I suspected the files were not resized

Comment: @SreeramTP It seems this is a known problem: https://forums.fast.ai/t/why-doesnt-opencv-seem-to-work-with-multiprocessing/14743/2 Given this, I'll re-write for threads rather than processes (easier anyway, just it usually doesn't allow much perf gain because GIL).

Comment: I will try running the code and let you know the results

Comment: @SreeramTP I might also suggest replacing `opencv`, with something like `skimage` or `PIL`. They each have their advantages, and you may find one might work here better than another.

Comment: I tried you code, it showed progress bar and stuff but no resizing

Comment: @SreeramTP I found myself a folder of large images on my computer and `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool` fixes the exact problem you describe. If you're still getting the same issue, you must not have adapted the code correctly. I will edit with the exact code I ran..

Comment: It is running fine now. But as you said no much improvement in the performance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183130/discussion-between-aaron-and-sreeram-tp).